# How to link multiple uploaded files in IFileFormCollection to corresponding complex model fields?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, file-upload, multipartform-data

I need to implement API for server-to-server communication that will send files in the same request as some JSON data to ensure atomicity and avoid saving files without related data or vice versa.

I found a solution for a single file upload together with JSON:
https://thomaslevesque.com/2018/09/04/handling-multipart-requests-with-json-and-file-uploads-in-asp-net-core/

But the problem is that my JSON model is more complex. A simplified example that attempts to cover all the cases I expect to see:

```
class RootModel
{
    public string SomeField { get; set; }
    public IList<ChildModel> FilesWithDescriptions { get; set; }
    public IFormFile MainFile { get; set; }
    public IFormFile SomeOtherFile { get; set; }
}

class ChildModel
{
    public string FileDescription { get; set; }
    public IFormFileCollection SomeNestedFiles { get; set; }
}
```

`MainFile` and `SomeOtherFile` are bound correctly, but the problem is with `FilesWithDescriptions -> SomeNestedFiles` collection - `SomeNestedFiles` is always null.

I tried the following in Postman

FilesWithDescriptions[0]SomeNestedFiles

and

FilesWithDescriptions[0].SomeNestedFiles

but still FormFileModelBinder does not set SomeNestedFiles. Not sure, if that's because I pass the field names in wrong format or if FormFileModelBinder does not recurse inside the model and I'll have to implement recursion myself. Will have to look inside FormFileModelBinder source code.

**How to implement it to keep correct associations between every uploaded file and the nested model collection fields?**

Comment: How did you try the code?If you write the json with the correct property name and value.It would not mix up the files.Or maybe you want to custom model binding to make this work?

Comment: `MainFile` and `SomeOtherFile` are bound correctly, but the problem is with FilesWithDescriptions -> SomeNestedFiles. I cannot find how to specify their names when uploading. Tried the following in Postman `FilesWithDescriptions[0]SomeNestedFiles` and `FilesWithDescriptions[0].SomeNestedFiles` but FormFileModelBinder does not set them. Not sure, if that's because I pass the field names in wrong format or if FormFileModelBinder does not recurse inside the model and I'll have to implement recursion myself. Will have to look inside FormFileModelBinder source code.

Answer (score 0):

I kinda "gave up" and implemented my own hacky mechanism integrated into custom model binder. It traverses the deserialized JSON object to find all kinds of IFormFile and then attempts to extract them from Request by matching anyCase name, and also using recursive path into properties and collections.

```
    // partially borrowed from
    // https://thomaslevesque.com/2018/09/04/handling-multipart-requests-with-json-and-file-uploads-in-asp-net-core/
    public class JsonWithFilesFormDataModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        // code from FormFileModelBuilder
        private class FileCollection : ReadOnlyCollection<IFormFile>, IFormFileCollection
        {
            public FileCollection(List<IFormFile> list)
                : base(list)
            {
            }

            public IFormFile this[string name] => GetFile(name);

            public IFormFile GetFile(string name)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    var file = Items[i];
                    if (string.Equals(name, file.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        return file;
                    }
                }

                return null;
            }

            public IReadOnlyList<IFormFile> GetFiles(string name)
            {
                var files = new List<IFormFile>();
                for (var i = 0; i < Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    var file = Items[i];
                    if (string.Equals(name, file.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        files.Add(file);
                    }
                }

                return files;
            }
        }

        private readonly IOptions<MvcJsonOptions> _jsonOptions;

        const string JSON_PART_FIELD_NAME = "json";

        public JsonWithFilesFormDataModelBinder(IOptions<MvcJsonOptions> jsonOptions)
        {
            _jsonOptions = jsonOptions;
        }

        public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            if (bindingContext == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));

            var request = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request;
            if (!request.HasFormContentType)
                return;

            // Retrieve the form part containing the JSON
            var valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(JSON_PART_FIELD_NAME);
            if (valueResult == ValueProviderResult.None)
            {
                // The JSON was not found
                var message = bindingContext.ModelMetadata.ModelBindingMessageProvider.MissingBindRequiredValueAccessor(bindingContext.FieldName);
                bindingContext.ModelState.TryAddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, message);
                return;
            }

            var rawValue = valueResult.FirstValue;

            // Deserialize the JSON
            var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(rawValue, bindingContext.ModelType, _jsonOptions.Value.SerializerSettings);

            if (model == null)
            {
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
                return; // nothing to do
            }

            // could not use FormFileModelBinder because don't know how to recurse into collections
            // doing it manually from request instead

            // collecting all file fields

            // code from FormFileModelBinder
            var form = await request.ReadFormAsync();
            ICollection<IFormFile> postedFiles = new List<IFormFile>();

            foreach (var file in form.Files)
            {
                // If there is an <input type="file" ... /> in the form and is left blank.
                if (file.Length == 0 || string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FileName))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                postedFiles.Add(file);
            }

            // now recursively step through the deserialized model
            // and fill all the recognized IFormFile and IFormFileCollection fields
            TryAssignFormFiles(model, postedFiles);

            // Set the successfully constructed model as the result of the model binding
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
        }

        private void TryAssignFormFiles(object model, ICollection<IFormFile> postedFiles, string path = "")
        {
            // fill all the recognized IFormFile and IFormFileCollection fields

            var props = model.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            foreach (var property in props)
            {
                var pt = property.PropertyType;

                var formFieldPath = path + property.Name;

                var matchingFiles = postedFiles.Where(p => p.Name.Equals(formFieldPath,
                    StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

                if (typeof(IFormFile).IsAssignableFrom(pt))
                {
                    if (matchingFiles.Count() != 1)
                    {
                        // ambiguous, cannot process more or zero files for single item
                        continue;
                    }

                    property.SetValue(model, matchingFiles.First());
                    continue;
                }
                else if (typeof(IFormFile[]).IsAssignableFrom(pt))
                {
                    if (matchingFiles.Count() > 0)
                        property.SetValue(model, matchingFiles.ToArray());
                    continue;
                }
                else if (typeof(IList<IFormFile>).IsAssignableFrom(pt))
                {
                    if (matchingFiles.Count() > 0)
                        property.SetValue(model, matchingFiles.ToList());
                    continue;
                }
                else if (typeof(IFormFileCollection).IsAssignableFrom(pt))
                {
                    if (matchingFiles.Count() > 0)
                        property.SetValue(model, new FileCollection(matchingFiles.ToList()));
                    continue;
                }

                // if got here, then field was not a file or a collection of files
                // attempt to recurse deeper

                // is this enumerable? ignore strings that are enumerable chars
                if (!typeof(string).IsAssignableFrom(pt) &&
                    typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(pt))
                {
                    if (!(property.GetValue(model) is IEnumerable ienum))
                        continue;

                    int seq = 0;
                    foreach (var ev in ienum)
                    {
                        TryAssignFormFiles(ev, postedFiles, path + $"{property.Name}[{seq}].");
                        seq++;
                    }
                }
                else // not a collection
                     // ignore primitives and nullable primitives
                if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(pt) == null &&
                    !pt.IsValueType && !pt.IsEnum)
                {
                    // some class-like thing, recurse into it
                    // TODO: what about dictionaries that are struct KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>?
                    // for now, assuming we won't be receiving those in our JSON
                    // because usually dictionary-like objects should be mapped to .NET class properties instead
                    var val = property.GetValue(model);
                    if (val == null)
                        continue;

                    TryAssignFormFiles(val, postedFiles, path + $"{property.Name}.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Testing data structures:

```
    public class RootModel
    {
        public string SomeField { get; set; }
        public IList<ChildModel> FilesWithDescriptions { get; set; }
        public IFormFile MainFile { get; set; }
        public IFormFile SomeOtherFile { get; set; }
    }

    public class ChildModel
    {
        public string FileDescription { get; set; }
        public IFormFileCollection SomeNestedFiles { get; set; }
        public IFormFile SomeNestedFile { get; set; }
        public IFormFile[] SomeNestedFilesArray { get; set; }
        public IList<IFormFile> SomeNestedFilesList { get; set; }
    }
```

Test controller method:

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> AcceptJsonMultipart([ModelBinder(typeof(JsonWithFilesFormDataModelBinder))]RootModel model)
```

Postman setup:

[image: Postman setup for multipart JSON with nested files]

JSON field in Postman:

```
{       
    "someField":"hello",
    "filesWithDescriptions":[
        {
            "fileDescription":"a file"
        },
        {
            "fileDescription":"b file"
        }
    ]
}
```

In general, it works, although it sacrifices .NET ModelBinder mechanisms (custom field names, validators etc.). If anybody knows a better way, you are very welcome to suggest something less hacky.